# Change system font

Tags: fonts

My phone has near stock Android Nougat 7.1.1 and it's rooted. I'm trying to figure out how change default font in system. There's no option to do this in system preferences. I know that fonts are kept in /system/font directory. In which config file in system fonts preferences are kept? I'm not interested in automatic changes made by app like Font Fix etc.. I want to change it by myself.

Comment: Have you already checked with our [fonts tag-wiki](/tags/fonts/info) and [answered 'fonts' questions](/search?q=[fonts]+answers%3A1)? No solution there?

Comment: Yes, can't find answer. I found some files in `/system/etc/` but I need to check it first before answer paste.